# Information Theoretic View of Stein's Lemma

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are two probability distributions on a, say finite alphabet set $\mathbb{X}$. Suppose that a Statistician has to decide between $P$ and $Q$ based on an i.i.d. sample $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_k =:X^k\in\mathbb{X}^k$. The decision is based on a set $A\subset\mathbb{X}^k$ (*decision region*) such that $P$ is accepted if $X^k\in A$, else $Q$ is accepted.

In this set-up, what we are interested in is (the *probability of error*),

$$\beta(k,\epsilon) := \min_{A\subseteq \mathbb{X}^k:P^k(A)\ge 1-\epsilon}Q^k(A),$$
where $P^k(x^k):=\prod_{i=1}^{k}P(x_i)$ and $Q^k(x^k):=\prod_{i=1}^{k}Q(x_i)$.

Stein's lemma says that
\begin{equation}
\tag{*}\label{*}
 \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k}\log \beta(k,\epsilon) = -D(P\|Q),
\end{equation}
where $$D(P\|Q):=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{X}}P(x)\log\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}.$$
Interestingly, while proving the above result, what we make use of is the following set (also called a *$\delta$-typical set* in information theory), which also looks practically feasible to handle with:
\begin{equation}
B(k,\delta) := \left\{x^k: -D(P\|Q)-\delta\le\frac{1}{k}\log\frac{P^k(x^k)}{Q^k(x^k)}\le -D(P\|Q)+\delta\right\}.
\end{equation}
We make use of the above set to achieve the limit in \eqref{*}. My question is, is this the case in statistics too? That is, do we use the set $B(k,\delta)$ as the decision region in statistics too? If so, what $\delta$ one should choose? Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: I asked the [same question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564327/information-theoretic-view-of-steins-lemma) in stat.stackexchange where it didn't seem to attract many users. So I'm asking here.

Comment: $\delta= \min\{\epsilon, 1-\epsilon \}$ works for the choice of $B(k,\delta)$ as the acceptance region in the Neyman-Pearson hypothesis test.  Since $P^k(B(k,\delta)^c) = 1- P^k(B(k,\delta))<\delta<\min\{ \epsilon, 1-\epsilon \} \le \epsilon$